# Storing BaseTemplateID and not custom Web Template ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm a bit confused regarding what I am seeing. I have two custom Web Templates, both of them are in the same format: `{F1FCFC29-8FD1-4016-BC33-B03B00C50C03}#MinimalWebTemplate`. That is what I expect, a GUID then the name attribute from the `WebTemplate` definition.

After the site is created and then iterating through all the sites using `getSubwebsForCurrentUser`, I am expecting the same value when calling `web.get_webTemplate()`. But what I am getting is either BDR or STS, which is aligned to the `BaseTemplateName` attribute of the `WebTemplate` definition.

If the `BaseTemplateName` is being attached to the site, then how am I supposed to iterate through all the sites and find the used my custom web template?

By the way, this is all using JavaScript inside a SharePoint Hosted Application using O365.

*edit* essentially what I need to do is call `g_wsaSiteTemplateId` but in the context of the site I'm iterating. Not sure how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how SharePoint web templates work - the `Configuration` and `WebTemplate` properties always match the base site template. The best practice is to add your custom web template name to the property bag within your web template package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <PropertyBag ParentType="Web">
    <Property Name="CustomWebTemplate" Type="string" Value="MyCustomWebTemplateName" />
  </PropertyBag>
</Elements>
```

You can then use this property bag value to get the custom web template name as you iterate through the sites.

Comment: thank you, I'll give that a shot in the next couple of days

Comment: when I add that attribute to my template it no longer is rendered as an option. so I'm going to assume that this attribute is not supported with O365

Comment: @bitterac, I'd be really surprised if this wasn't supported in O365. Please take a look at the following article to make sure that the element is created in the right place in your project: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#stepbystep

Comment: I swear that I've read that post, which is the only reliable post on the entire internet, 5 times. I'll read it again. thanks for checking in.

Comment: so here is the problem, in that example Vesku is setting the property bag in a feature that is site scoped, then using code to activate that feature. The code fires when the web template is added to the site. that actually isn't what I want, but we are close. thanks

Comment: @bitterac, the event receiver is a way to activate a site collection feature during a subsite creation. If you add the property bag element to a Web-scoped feature and then include that feature in the WebFeatures section of your onet.xml then this approach will work without any custom code.

Comment: well hot damn that worked like a charm. I owe you one. Enjoy your new found karma.